# How to Setup an Image Database on a Server?

Tags: ios, sql, objective-c, sql-server, cocoa-touch

I have an app that I am working on, and I want it to go to my server, get a title, image and description and display it for the user. I have a good deal of experience with iOS app development, but the server side stuff...well not so much. I was thinking that I might just add a separate XML file on the server for each item that I want to display info for...but I know there are more effective options. Should I use a SQL database? I realize that this is quite a broad question, but I just need a push in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: If you identify your users, I recommand using a MySQL database and handling the requests with PHP. They are both easy to learn.

Comment: It can be totally anonymous. It is not an account based app. I will look into those though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know how to set up your own server, so i'm using third parties.

I'm using amazon s3, it's pretty simple to use, you can store there files that < 1gb.

> Create iPad, iPhone, and iPod applications that leverage AWS using the
>   AWS SDK for iOS. The SDK helps remove complexity by providing iOS APIs
>   for many AWS services including Amazon S3, Amazon SQS, Amazon SNS, and
>   DynamoDB. The single, downloadable package includes the AWS iOS
>   Library, code samples, and documentation.

Here's [manual](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforios/).

But there's a lot other good providers for storing your data, please read this article:

- [RayWenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20482/how-to-choose-the-best-backend-provider-for-your-ios-app-parse-vs-stackmob-vs-appcelerator-cloud-and-more)

Parse.com have good tutorials(photo server) for quick start with it - https://parse.com/tutorials